# Execute command on each node

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

Background: Have approx 50 nodes "behind" a namespace. Meaning that a given Pod in this namespace can land on any of those 50 nodes.

The task is to test if an outbound firewall rule (in a FW outside the cluster) has been implemented correctly. Therefore I would like to test a command **on each potential node** in the namespace which will tell me if I can reach my target from the given node. (using `curl` for such test but that is besides the point for my question)

I can create a small containerized app which will exit 0 on success. Then next step would be execute this on each potential node and harvest the result. How to do that?

(I don't have access to the nodes directly, only indirectly via Kubernetes/OpenShift. I only have access to the namespace-level, not the cluster-level.)

Answer (score 1):

The underlying node firewall settings is NOT control by K8s network policies. To test network connectivity in a namespace you only need to run 1 pod in that namespace. To test firewall settings of the node you typically ssh into the node and execute command  to test - while this is possible with K8s but that would require the pod to run with root privileged; which not applicable to you as you only has access to a single namespace.

Comment: "To test network connectivity in a namespace you only need to run 1 pod in that namespace". Not sure about that. The FW has no knowledge about the Kubernetes cluster. It knows IP source addresses (input manually for each of the 50 nodes), that's it. So the risk that FW engineer has made a data entry error is not to be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

> Then next step would be execute this on each potential node and
> harvest the result. How to do that?

As **gohm'c** answer you can not run Command on Nodes unless you have access to Worker nodes. You need to have SSH access to check the firewall on **Nodes**.

If you are planning to just run container app on specific types of nodes, or on all the Nodes you can follow below answer

You can create the **deployment** or you can use the **Deamon** **set** if want to run on each node.

Deployment could be useful if you are planning to run on specific nodes, you have to use in that case [Node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) or [Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes-using-node-affinity/).

[Daemon set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) will deploy and run containers on all existing Nodes. So you can choose accordingly.

Comment: For Deployment:  I would need 50 x DeploymentConfig each with its own node selector ??  Since it is a `DeploymentConfig` Kubernetes would keep those Pods permanently alive just for the sake of testing a single command?  (I would run out of resources!). I think you mean I would need to (for each node):  (1) Create DeploymentConfig with node selector, (2) Somehow harvest the result from the Pod, (3) Remove DeploymentConfig.

Comment: For DaemonSet: I think it has something going for it. However, it will create a massive load on the cluster. (I will run out of resources). Not to run out of resources I would need something which would test each node in turn. A DaemonSet will bring up a Pod on each and every node in my selection (in my case 50 nodes) and the Pod will be  permanent. I need a one-shot execution for my purpose, probably more akin to the Kubernetes Job concept.

Comment: if you are planning for 5-10 pod you have to label them first and deploy the container or on them, if you want on all use deamon set. If you want to just run comamnd and remove cotnainer automatic use the Jobs instead of anything else.

Comment: You can keep one single YAML template file, using shell script tag one by one node. Write another shell scipt which will create new yaml from template yaml and update fields in it like node selector, and any other and at use same yaml to delete resource also. This way you can roll out one by one using simple shell script and yaml job or deployment template.